# Remote Desktop Services: CAP or RAP through PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop, gateway, new-item

I am trying to configure a new RDS gateway server through Powershell (for automatic setup after EC2 creation). The issue I'm running into right now is setting up a default or otherwise CAP and RAP. Everything else seems to work just fine, and if I go through the server dialogs and point and click my way to doing the CAP/RAP wizard, it all works. Until I do so, those policies don't exist (not even a default).

The code I'm using, which I sourced from blog posts on technet about the subject, is this:

```
new-item -Force -Credential $AdminCredentials -path RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP -Name DomainAdmin-CAP -UserGroups “$AdminGroupName@$NetBiosDomainName" -AuthMethod 1
new-item -Force -Credential $AdminCredentials -path RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP -Name DomainUser-CAP -UserGroups “$UserGroupName@$NetBiosDomainName" -AuthMethod 1

new-item -Force -Credential $AdminCredentials -path RDS:\GatewayServer\RAP -Name DomainAdmin-RAP -UserGroups “$AdminGroupName@$NetBiosDomainName" -ComputerGroupType 2
new-item -Force -Credential $AdminCredentials -path RDS:\GatewayServer\RAP -Name DomainUser-RAP -UserGroups “$UserGroupName@$NetBiosdomainName" -ComputerGroupType 2
```

Again, everything else works and the system is 100% and useable once I RDP in to the server and set these up manually, so my only issue is this automation step. The error I'm getting when I run my script is this:

> new-item : Access to the object at RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP\DomainAdmin-CAP is denied for the cmdlet
>   New-Item.The supplied  value is not valid, or you do not have
>   sufficient permissions. At line:89 char:1
>   + new-item -Force -Credential $AdminCredentials -path RDS:\GatewayServe ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [New-Item], AccessViolationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PermissionDenied,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Edit: Things I have tried based on suggestions and frustration:

I have made all " characters uniform after someone pointed out they were actually not the same thing on the front and rear of my -UserGroup variable strings - No error change.

I have tried $NetBiosDomainName as the simple one word NetBIOS version (DOMAIN) as well as the full domain (domain.company.com) - No error change.

I have tried changing the "$AdministratorsGroupName@$NetBiosDomainName" string out for $AdminGroup (= $AdministratorsGroupName + "@" + $NetBiosDomainName") to simplify the input to the -UserGroups parameter - No error change

I have run this script as both the domain admin and local administrator account - No error change

Comment: Silly question, are you running this as an admin ? Also, are you using the `Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices`?

Comment: Yes. No silly questions. I am logged in as either Domain Admin or Local admin, and launching Powershell ISE as Admin. Yes I am running the Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices line earlier in the script (installing the features and everything, as the scripts takes it from base windows 2016 to functional gateway)

Comment: I just verified the following works(on a freshly installed Remote Desktop Services role) : `New-Item -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP -Name DomainAdmin-CAP -UserGroups "test@domain.local" -AuthMethod 1 `. Confirmed with `Get-ChildItem -Path RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP` Now, I did do this from my local PC using: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server` . If this example still gives you the error, then I would look more into how this is being executed.

Comment: Use either PSSession or Invoke-Command to run it on the server remotely

Comment: I was running this script directly on the server itself, so local to where it should be creating the Items.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy paste or you actually have different quotes `“` `"` around your `UserGroups` param. Powershell can deal with curly/smart quotes but it's best to avoid them.

Comment: That's a great catch James, thanks. I retyped my code in ISE which actually did have the 2 different types of quotes (TIL), so it's uniform now... however it did not change the error I am getting.

Comment: Based on the fact that you're using a NetBIOS name, I'm assuming that you're on a non-domain server.  Have you verified that `$AdminGroupName` on `$NetBiosDomainName` actually exists?  That was my problem.  I had to actually create the local group.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following script to configure a Remote Access Gateway on a non-domain Windows 2019/2016 server.  This includes a CAP, a RAP, and a ManagedComputerGroup.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name "RDS-Gateway" -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools > $null
Import-Module -Name RemoteDesktopServices

#=============User Modifiable=============#
$GroupName="SG_RemoteUsers@$env:COMPUTERNAME"
# No Restrictions
#$GroupName="Users@BUILTIN"
$ManagedComputers="RDG_RDCBComputers"
# Managed Computer Groups
$MCGComputers=@($env:COMPUTERNAME,"<target machines>")
$MCGs=@(@{Name="RDG_RDCBComputers";Desc="All RDCB Computers in the deployment";Computers=$MCGComputers})
# Connection Authorization Policies
$CAPs=@(@{Name="RDG_CAP_AllUsers";UserGroups=$GroupName;AuthMethod=1;Status=1})
# Resrouce Authorization Policies
$RAPs=@(@{Name="RDG_AllComputers";UserGroups=$GroupName;ComputerGroupType=2;ComputerGroup=$null})

# If you already have a certificate, skip this part.
<#region Certificate
$FilePath="C:\temp\export.cer"
$SelfSigned=New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -DnsName $env:COMPUTERNAME -FriendlyName $env:COMPUTERNAME -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -HashAlgorithm "SHA256" -KeyDescription "RDG Key" -KeyLength 4096 -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment -KeyUsageProperty All
$CertPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String “password” -Force –AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $SelfSigned.PSPath -FilePath $FilePath -Password $CertPassword > $null
Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root" -FilePath $FilePath -Password $CertPassword > $null
Remove-Item -Path $FilePath
$Certificate=$SelfSigned
#endregion
#>
$Certificate=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Thumbprint -eq "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1

#=============Do not modify=============#
$CAPPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP"
$RAPPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\RAP"
$MCGPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups"

#=============Script=============#
# Add the certificate to RDS
Set-Item -Path "RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint" -Value $Certificate.Thumbprint

try { Get-LocalGroup -Name $GroupName -ErrorAction Stop > $null }
catch { New-LocalGroup -Name $GroupName > $null }

try { Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $GroupName -Member "<user that should have access>" -ErrorAction Stop > $null }
catch { Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $GroupName -Member "<user that should have access>" > $null }

# Remove existing items (must be done in the order of CAP and/or RAP first, then GatewayManagedComputerGroups
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)") { Remove-Item -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }
$RAPs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$RAPPath\$($_.Name)") { Remove-Item -Path "$RAPPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }
$MCGs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$MCGPath\$($_.Name)") { Remove-Item -Path "$MCGPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }

$MCGs | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $MCGPath -Name $_.Name -Description $_.Desc -Computers $_.Computers > $null }
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $CAPPath -Name $_.Name -UserGroups $_.UserGroups -AuthMethod $_.AuthMethod -Status $_.Status > $null }
$RAPs | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $RAPPath -Name $_.Name -UserGroups $_.UserGroups -ComputerGroupType $_.ComputerGroupType > $null }

# Stop redirection of Serial Ports
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { Set-Item -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)\DeviceRedirection\SerialPorts" -Value 0 }

Restart-Service -Name "TSGateway"
```

This script, which shares a significant portion of the previous, is what I used to configure the same on a server that is a member of an AD domain.  It's not the only way to do it, but hopefully it will give you a head start.

There is a portion of this script that creates the necessary AD group.

The only part that's missing is that the certificate must be placed in the **Trusted Root** store on the PC *from which you want to connect*.

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name "RDS-Gateway" -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools > $null
Import-Module -Name RemoteDesktopServices
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement 

#=============User Modifiable=============#
$GroupName="SG_RemoteUsers"
$ManagedComputers="RDG_RDCBComputers"
# Managed Computer Groups
$MCGComputers=@($env:COMPUTERNAME,"<target machines>")
$MCGs=@(@{Name=$ManagedComputers;Desc="All RDCB Computers in the deployment";Computers=$MCGComputers})
# Connection Authorization Policies
$CAPs=@(@{Name="RDG_CAP_AllUsers";UserGroups="$GroupName@$env:USERDOMAIN";AuthMethod=1;Status=1})
# Resrouce Authorization Policies
$RAPs=@(@{Name="RDG_AllDomainComputers";UserGroups="$GroupName@$env:USERDOMAIN";ComputerGroupType=1;ComputerGroup="Domain Computers@$env:USERDOMAIN"},
        @{Name="RDG_RDConnectionBrokers";UserGroups="Domain Users@$env:USERDOMAIN";ComputerGroupType=0;ComputerGroup=$ManagedComputers})

# If you already have a certificate, skip this part.
<#region Certificate
$FilePath="C:\temp\export.cer"
$SelfSigned=New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -DnsName "$env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN" -FriendlyName $env:COMPUTERNAME -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -HashAlgorithm "SHA256" -KeyDescription "RDG Key" -KeyLength 4096 -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DataEncipherment -KeyUsageProperty All
$CertPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String “password” -Force –AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $SelfSigned.PSPath -FilePath $FilePath -Password $CertPassword > $null
Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root" -FilePath $FilePath -Password $CertPassword > $null
Remove-Item -Path $FilePath
$Certificate=$SelfSigned
#endregion
#>
$Certificate=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Thumbprint -eq "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" } | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1

#=============Do not modify=============#
$CAPPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\CAP"
$RAPPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\RAP"
$MCGPath="RDS:\GatewayServer\GatewayManagedComputerGroups"

#=============Script=============#
# Add the certificate to RDS
Set-Item -Path "RDS:\GatewayServer\SSLCertificate\Thumbprint" -Value $Certificate.Thumbprint

$ADGroup=[System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]::new("(&(objectCategory=Group)(samAccountName=$GroupName))").FindOne()
if ($ADGroup -ne $null) {
  $ADGroup=$ADGroup.GetDirectoryEntry()
  $Parent=[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]::new($ADGroup.Parent)
  $Parent.Children.Remove($ADGroup)
  $Parent.CommitChanges()
  $Parent.Close()
}

$ADGroup=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain),$GroupName)
$ADGroup.Description="Remote Gateway Users Group"
$ADGroup.GroupScope=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupScope]::Global
$ADGroup.IsSecurityGroup=$true
$Member=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain),"Administrator")
$ADGroup.Members.Add($Member)
$Member=[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain),"admin_jeberhardt")
$ADGroup.Members.Add($Member)
$ADGroup.DisplayName=$ADGroup.SamAccountName
$ADGroup.Save()
$OU=[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]::new("LDAP://$($ADGroup.DistinguishedName)")
$NewOU=[System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry]::new("LDAP://OU=<target OU>,DC=<domain name>,DC=com")
$OU.MoveTo($NewOU)
$OU.CommitChanges()
$OU.Close()
$NewOU.Close()

# Remove existing items (must be done in the order of CAP and/or RAP first, then GatewayManagedComputerGroups
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)") { Write-Verbose "Removing $($_.Name)"; Remove-Item -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }
$RAPs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$RAPPath\$($_.Name)") { Write-Verbose "Removing $($_.Name)"; Remove-Item -Path "$RAPPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }
$MCGs | ForEach-Object { if (Test-Path -Path "$MCGPath\$($_.Name)") { Write-Verbose "Removing $($_.Name)"; Remove-Item -Path "$MCGPath\$($_.Name)" -Recurse } }

$MCGs | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "Creating $($_.Name)"; New-Item -Path $MCGPath -Name $_.Name -Description $_.Desc -Computers $_.Computers > $null }
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "Creating $($_.Name)"; New-Item -Path $CAPPath -Name $_.Name -UserGroups $_.UserGroups -AuthMethod $_.AuthMethod -Status $_.Status > $null }
$RAPs | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "Creating $($_.Name)"; New-Item -Path $RAPPath -Name $_.Name -UserGroups $_.UserGroups -ComputerGroup $_.ComputerGroup -ComputerGroupType $_.ComputerGroupType > $null }

# Stop redirection of Serial Ports
$CAPs | ForEach-Object { Set-Item -Path "$CAPPath\$($_.Name)\DeviceRedirection\SerialPorts" -Value 0 }

Restart-Service -Name "TSGateway"
```